# Function without var in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a function that takes a string and a case class as input and return string as output.

Different case class gets appended to the list and the final case class is returned which has the list.

I want to do it without using var. The val list would be immutable and no data would be added to it. Is there any other way of doing it in Scala way?

```
def getResult(eventName: Option[String], content: Content): String = {
  var list = List.empty[Json]
  val device = Device(
      DEVICE_SCHEMA,
      data = content.data.device
    )
  list = list :+ device.asJson

  val parser = Parser(
      PARSER_SCHEMA,
      data = content.data.parser
    )
  list = list :+ parser.asJson
  val res = Result(
      RESULT_SCHMEA,
      data = list
    )
  res.asJson.noSpaces
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try inlining list creation like so

```
def getResult(eventName: Option[String], content: Content): String = {
  val device = Device(
    DEVICE_SCHEMA,
    data = content.data.device
  )
  val parser = Parser(
    PARSER_SCHEMA,
    data = content.data.parser
  )
  Result(
    RESULT_SCHMEA,
    data = List(device.asJson, parser.asJson)  // <== inline list creation
  ).asJson.noSpaces
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some little changes from the previous answer.
You don't need `val res` and it's preferred to create the list outside `Result` for easier reading and later debugging:

```
def getResult(eventName: Option[String], content: Content): String = {
  val device = Device(
    DEVICE_SCHEMA,
    data = content.data.device
  )
  val parser = Parser(
    PARSER_SCHEMA,
    data = content.data.parser
  )

  val jsons = List(device.asJson, parser.asJson)
  Result(
    RESULT_SCHMEA,
    data = jsons
  ).asJson.noSpaces
}
```